# What is the function of " *| " operator in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

What is the function of the "`*|`" operator in Verilog?

```
parameter LANES = 4,           
parameter CONVERTERS = 4,                   
parameter SAMPLE_SIZE = 16,    
parameter SAMPLES = 1          

wire [SAMPLES*SAMPLE_SIZE*(CONVERTERS+(LANES-CONVERTERS%LANES)*|(CONVERTERS%LANES))-1:0] tx_dataout;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*|` is not a single operator, but the combination of two different ones. Unary reduction OR `|`, followed by a multiplication `*`.

The code:

```
CONVERTERS+(LANES-CONVERTERS%LANES)*|(CONVERTERS%LANES)
```

is equivalent to:

```
CONVERTERS + ( LANES - ( CONVERTERS % LANES )) * ( |( CONVERTERS % LANES ))
```

Basically if `CONVERTERS` is a multiple of `LANES` (modulo remainder is 0), then `|(CONVERTERS%LANES)` will be `0`, otherwise it will be `1`. This is then multiplied by the `(LANES-CONVERTERS%LANES)` part to set ot to zero if a multiple, otherwise resulting in `LANES-remainder`.

This could be rewritten equivalently as:

```
CONVERTERS + ((CONVERTERS % LANES) ? (LANES - CONVERTERS % LANES) : 0)
```

Albeit the former preserves the the width of the constants.

Alternatively you could use:

```
CONVERTERS + ((LANES - CONVERTERS % LANES) % LANES)
```

Comment: In terms of style, the above ternary operator at a minimum would be preferred over the "*|" coding style. That obscure style stems from the desire to write unbranched code. It doesn't matter for Verilog (or VHDL) but S/W compilers decades ago needed this as a hint or starting point to compile (C-) code into unbranched assembly which is easier speed up with pipeline/look-ahead.